# Firebase FCM Notification issue in OREO version Android Phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integration Firebase FCM notification in my android app, but I have send notification in backed to all app user that time notification send with all user but problem is android OREO version mobile app user don't show notification

Comment: please help me friends?

Comment: we are not your friends, pal.

Comment: So how to add in my friend list @Marcin Orlowski

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the notification channel for the notification?

Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel or it will not appear.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels